# bootstrap responsive image inside div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

basically what i need is:
3 columns (for an example col-ms-4)
inside each of the columns i need a div
inside the div:
the top half of the div an responsive image and the bottom

and

i cant manage to make the image half of the div and responsive

```
 <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="service-box">
                    <img class="service-box-img img-responsive" src="something">
                    <h2>Header</h2>
                    sdfsdfdfdsfsdfdsfdf
                </div>
             </div>

css:

 .col-sm-4{
            padding-left:100px;
                padding-right:100px;
            height:300px;

        }
        .service-box{
            background-color:white;
            padding:30px;
            padding-left:100px;
        }
        .service-box-img{

            height:150px;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a

```
.col-sm-4 img {
     width: 100%
}
```